# Cannot put a file into samba share using smbclient NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED error

Tags: permissions, samba

I can't put a file into shared folder using smbclient. However, I can do it without any problems using Ubuntu GUI. I'm trying to create a share which would be open for writing but close for reading. "/home/XXXXXXXXX/hw_info/IN" folder has 333(d-wx-wx-wx) permissions. If I allow others to read (d-wx-wxrwx) then I can create a new file in the share.
Another hint is that if there is a file in the share which already created by guest then I can rewrite it but I cannot create/write a new one.
I restarted samba after changing the configuration file.

smb.conf

```
[HwInfo]
    path = /home/XXXXXXXXX/hw_info/IN
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    write list = all
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    inherit permissions = no
```

Terminal:

```
smbclient //XXXXXXXXX/HwInfo -N -c "put test.txt test1.txt"
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.25]
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED opening remote file \test1.txt
```

I realize that there is a problem with permissions but I can't figure out where it is and how to fix it.

BTW what is the difference between terminal and GUI access to samba share. Why can I do it using GUI but cannot in the command line?

EDIT: I realized that GUI mounts the share firstly and then uses it. I've tried to mount my share in the command line, but I also obtained permission error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/samba/share/test.txt': Permission denied
```