# Is it possible to create a network share which has write-only permissions for everyone

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I need to create a shared folder on the server in which everyone could write new files but nobody can read any information.

Since I already have Samba on the server I've tried to use it. I created a new folder with write-only(333) permissions and added a new Samba share.

However, I have run into a problem [which I described here.](https://askubuntu.com/q/946668/725762)

Is there another way to create such a share or to cope with my task?

Comment: Nope. Samba needs read permissions to do its own stuff. Mind though it should what bindfs is created for https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bindfs/

Comment: @Rinzwind It looks like what I'm looking for. Thanks, I'll try it out. Nonetheless, how can Ubuntu GUI does it though smbclient cannot?

Comment: @Rinzwind I read about bindfs and came to a conclusion that it won't help me solve my problem cause it works only with local FS